# Ubuntu 18.04 startup questions regarding runlevels and *.wants directories

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, upstart, runlevel

1. Is Ubuntu 18.04 using [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) or [systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd)?
2. I know with the directories named *Rc0.d* Rc1.d *Rc2.d* ......*Rc6.d*. we can control runlevels in Ubuntu 18.04. But what is the difference between what they do, and the `*.wants` directories?

Comment: “So I know with these directories…” — What directories? Please don't assume that we know what you are thinking. Edit you question to make it clear what you are asking. (Note: I only pointed out the first problem that I found)

Comment: Your question is a good one, don't worry on the voting score!

Comment: No voting is nothing, what is important is to understand what i don't, But after doing some studying and searching inside my Ubuntu18.04 i came to a conclusion that the Upstart directories are just there in Ubuntu in case someone wanted to switch back to upstart because all the services and the .target and the target.wants files are connected and can alter the system runlevels. So thank you for giving your opinion and your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

1. The [Packages list for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/) shows, in the [admin section](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/admin/), that [systemd](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd) is used, not [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).  Ubuntu even provides a [comparison](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers).
2. [*.wants directories](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) hook units into the start-up of other units, without having to modify their unit files. Units are 'plain text ini-style file that encodes information about a service, a socket, a device, a mount point, an automount point, a swap file or partition, a **start-up target**, a watched file system path, a timer controlled and supervised by systemd(1), a resource management slice or a group of externally created processes.' [Runlevels](https://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel) are exposed via "target units" by [systemd](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd). 
   By contrast, good ol' [Sysinit](http://sysinit.sourceforge.net/) used the *Rc?.d* files to change runlevels, and that still works if you override what systemd did. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Ubuntu) has a useful explanation.

Comment: A better way to find this out is to read the release notes for that and earlier versions, which address this specific point.  https://askubuntu.com/a/780747/43344 https://askubuntu.com/a/613785/43344 https://askubuntu.com/a/622207/43344 https://askubuntu.com/a/1004563/43344

Comment: Thanks these were very useful to me ....

Comment: If the answer is good, click on the gray up arrowhead at left; if it's the best answer, please also click the checkmark to show others.